# When would you use a table-valued function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm currently learning about functions in sql server and I don't understand why/when you would use an [inline table valued function](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189294(v=sql.105).aspx).

I've tried reading about it and some examples but it is still unclear to me. Can someone explain or provide an easy to understand use-case scenario?

Comment: Although I voted to close (too broad), one situation where you want a table valued function is when you want a view that can take parameters.

Comment: Search for "String splitter" and you'll see one very common use of a table valued function. You use them in joins or Cross Applys to do a lot of useful things.

Comment: A split function as well on delimited values.

Comment: One system I built had a complex set of rules for determining the set of users authorized to perform an action or access specific documents. It was handy to bundle up all of the logic into TVFs that returned either a set of users who could perform a specified action or documents a particular user could access. (Rules like the document owner always has access _union_ documents assigned to the user's branch/division/region/corporation _union_ managers and other privileged users for the document owner's branch/division/region/corporation. A lot of fiddly JOINs with a simple result.)

Comment: *When would you use a table-valued function?* Simple answer: **As often as possible!** In one of my projects there is a final *Universe-VIEW* consisting of about 50 iTVFs (many of them hierachically nested), taking a big bunch of parameters. This big *GetMeAll-View* returns literally everything in about 1000 columns, can be called directly from Excel and is still really fast...

Comment: Agreed with @Shnugo. The only time I use an object other than a TVF is when I'm performing some sort of side-effecting operation that **forces** me to consider something else.

Comment: Table valued functions are a type of re-useable code.  Code re-use is almost always better than code repetition.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Table-valued functions are "just" parameterized views. This makes them extremely powerful for encapsulating logic that would otherwise be hidden behind an opaque stored procedure. Here's an example:

**Inline Table-valued Function:**

```
create function dbo.GetClients (
    @clientName nvarchar(max) = null
)
returns table
return (
    select *
    from dbo.Clients as a
    where ((a.ClientName = @clientName) or a.ClientName is null)
);
```

**Stored Procedure:**

```
create procedure dbo.usp_GetClients (
    @clientName nvarchar(max) = null
)
as
begin;
    select *
    from dbo.Clients as a
    where ((a.ClientName = @clientName) or a.ClientName is null)
end;
```

Unlike the stored procedure call, a table-valued function allows me to compose the logic from `dbo.GetClients` with other objects:

```
select *
from dbo.GetClients(N'ACME') as a
join ... as b
    on a.ClientId = b.ClientId
```

In such situations I cannot imagine using a stored procedure because of how restrictive it is when compared to the table-valued function. I would be forced to marshal the data around myself using a temp table, table variable, or application layer in order to combine results from multiple objects.

Inline table-valued functions are especially awesome because of the "inline" bit which is probably best explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion). This allows the optimizer to treat such functions no differently than the objects they encapsulate, resulting in near optimal performance plans (assuming that your indexes and statistics are ideal).

Answer (score 13):

This is a great question and a topic that's not discussed enough IMHO. Think of inline table valued functions as views that accept parameters. That's the short answer but let's dig a little deeper...

In SQL server you have three kinds of user-defined functions*: scalar functions (svf), multi-line table valued functions (mTVF) and inline table valued functions (iTVF). svfs return a single value, both mTVFs and iTVFs return a table. The difference between mTVFs and iTVFs is performance. In short - mTVFs are slow, iTVFs can be (and almost always are) much faster. mTVFs allow you to do things you couldn't do in a view (e.g. create temp tables, perform loops, utilize cursors...), iTVFs, again, have the same restrictions as views except for they can except parameters.

I use iTFVs for common data warehouse queries where I need a view that takes parameter and splitting/manipulating strings. A more advanced use of iTVFs which has changed my career is replacing scalar functions with iTVFs - see this article from Jeff Moden titled, "How to Make Scalar UDFs Run Faster": http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/91724/

- For simplicity I excluded the topic of CLR and other non T-SQL types of functions.